# HttpURLConnection connection variable not setting the values and getting HTTP response code: 401 exception

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect to a REST Endpoint from Java console application. To that endpoint, I need to provide a token and after that pass a JSON and get the response. I have written the code below but the connection variable is not updating with the set parameters and I am getting the exception below:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: ----------------------------------------------------------------
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.consoleapp.MemberServiceConsole.member(MemberServiceConsole.java:68)
at com.consoleapp.MemberServiceConsole.get(MemberServiceConsole.java:42)
at com.consoleapp.MemberServiceConsole.main(MemberServiceConsole.java:87)
```

Below is the code that I have written:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import org.json.JSONObject;

private void member(String accessToken) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(memberEnquiry);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        String token = "7gS6dxFg4doBko0TFhmRbWCJ0ermLsUp";
        
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "access_token " +token);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        try (OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String responseLine = null;
            while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(responseLine.trim());
            }
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 401 is an authorization error. Have you tried using `Bearer` instead of `access_token`?

Comment: Do you mean connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer {token}"); ? Yes I tried, it still shows the same.